# function inside a seeder giving Call to undefined function Termwind\ValueObjects\mb_strimwidth()

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-seeding

i have a project where i have a 'habits' table, and that table needs a seeder to give it data, simply put, its a seeder with raw data, and i need to cook it, in other terms i need to process it like so...

```php
public function run()
{
    $Habits = [
        'Good' => ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
        'Neutral' => ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't'],
        '☹️Bad' => ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    ];
        
    foreach ($habits as $habit_category => $names) {
        foreach ($names as $name) {
            DB::table('habits')->insert([
                'name' => $name,
                'category' => $habit_category
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the database seeder

```php
public function run()
{
    $this->call([
        HabitsSeeder::class,
    ]);
}
```

i know the logic is not flawed, but idk if im doing it right but anyway, the error given is in the title:

> "Call to undefined function Termwind\ValueObjects\mb_strimwidth()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Try these options,

- You can solve this issue by installing **mbstring** extension.

##### If you have XAMPP try this,

> *config* → *php ini* → search for
> ***;extension=mbstring*** → remove the semi colon (;)
> [image]

##### If you have MAC OS,

> sudo port install php80-mbstring

##### If you have Linux Based System,

> sudo apt-get install php8.1-mbstring

Once the extenson is installed, you need to restart your PHP server.

> service httpd restart

---

If you have any doubt please refer this blog,
https://sebhastian.com/mbstring-missing-php/

or you can simply prefer PHP documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php

Answer (score 7):

The error message is probably unrelated to your seeder. You're using the `nunomaduro/termwind` package, which is most likely referenced inside of a service provider.

When you call any artisan command like `db:seed`, those service providers are being booted up and any errors in them will block the seeder from even running.

The only place that package calls the `mb_strimwidth` inside the ValueObjects namespace is in this file:

https://github.com/nunomaduro/termwind/blob/8ab0b32c8caa4a2e09700ea32925441385e4a5dc/src/ValueObjects/Styles.php#L1053

Really the root issue is that you are missing the `mbstring` PHP extension. So when the Termwind package references an `mb_*` method, it can't find that method in the global namespace and instead checks the package's namespace, can't find it there either, and throws an error.

Take a look at [the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php) for how to install the `mbstring` package in your system.

Tip for debugging a future issue like this is to look at the entire error message **stack trace** not just the latest message. You'll be able to work backwards and see where this method is being called and what triggered it.